# Partial view doesn't refresh after $scope change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a classic scenario: filters on the left side, list of products on the right. User clicks on a filter, list of products refreshes.

I'm using 2 partial views, both views share the same controller.

```
<div class="row">
   <div ng-include="'/views/filters.html'"></div>
   <div ng-include="'/views/products.html'"></div>
</div>
```

The controller makes calls to a nodejs backend that talks to elasticsearch.

```
.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', function($scope, $http, $timeout){

$http.get('/getAll')
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.products = data.hits.hits;
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });

$scope.filterClick = function($event, filterClicked) {

    $http.get('/getSingleFilter', {
            params: {
                filter: filterClicked
            }
        })
        .success(function(data) {
            $timeout(function(){
              $scope.products = data;
              console.log($scope.products);
            });
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
}
}]);
```

The call to getAll works fine, products.html displays all products.
getSingleFilter doesn't refresh the list though. I do see the correct list printed in the console, but the view doesn't refresh.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Any specific reason why you are using `$timeout`? Judging by the code you provided, you dont need to use it. `$digest` cycle will be triggered by `$http`, and your model should be successfully updated as with your `$http.get('/getAll')` example

```
.success(function(data) {
     $scope.products = data;       
})
```

Comment: That's what I initially thought as well, so my first attempt was simply   $scope.products = data, but it didn't work. So then I tried with $timeout, no dice.

Comment: If you are sure that the correct data is returned , you can try $scope.$apply(function($scope) { $scope.products = data; }) This will start the digest loop if its not in progress

Comment: Calling $apply directly results in a "$digest already in progress" error. I tried wrapping the call with a check to !$scope.$$phase, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem. I put the 2 partials in the same partial, and put the code inside a

```
<div ng-controller='AppCtrl'>
```

and it worked.
Before I had the ng-controller='AppCtrl' directive show up in both partials and I think that was the issue. I may just leave it like this now, or create 2 controllers and then have a service to share the data.

Comment: even if it's the same controller, each time you use it, it create another $scope object inherited from the parent controller, so if the data aren't storedi in the parent controller (at least initialized as empty objects), this won't work.